# Trying to convert a column in SQL to simple duration (Column is like "3 Days 18 Hours 51 Minutes")

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, casting, type-conversion

I have a column in SQL that has several fields in the format of "3 Days 18 Hours 51 Minutes."  I was hoping someone could help change that duration into a plain number field like 5451 as the value.  Please help!

I've tried to potentially extract the minutes days and hours separately, but the positioning is off sometimes when the hours are a single number as opposed to 2 digit number.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields. (But a date has a year field, a month field, etc.)

Comment: Please provide a [MRE] with actual sample data (as opposed to a text description), actual desired results (as opposed to a text description) and your attempt.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and include more comprehensive sample data that includes various special cases. Will "1 Hours" appear as "1 Hour"? Will "0 Days" be omitted outright?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Can you provice more information? '3 Days 18 Hours 51 Minutes' should be what plain number and why? 31851? '3 Days 5 hours and 51 minutes' should be 30551? And  '3 Days 5 hours 5 minutes' should be 30505?

Comment: "3 Days 18 Hours 51 Minutes." -> 3 * 1440 + 18 * 60 + 51 = 5451 (minutes).

Comment: One approach https://dbfiddle.uk/l5loWtDt

Answer (score 4):

One approach would be to set up a table of `"<digits> <keyword>"` pattern strings to  recognize and extract the component parts. If the *multipler* is included in that table, it is not hard to extract the values, convert them to integers, apply the appropriate multiplier, and sum the results.

The following encodes the pattern table in a `VALUES` construct and uses several `CROSS APPLY`s to build up the desired result.

```
SELECT *
FROM Duration D
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        SUM(PAT.Multiplier * V.Value) AS Minutes
        --*
    FROM (
        VALUES
            -- The leading space is critical to the parse.
            -- Optional trailing 's' and trailing '.' are ignored
            -- Limits: 5 max digits for year, 2 max digits for hour and minute.
            ('% [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] Day%', 5, 1440),
            ('% [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] Day%', 4, 1440),
            ('% [0-9][0-9][0-9] Day%', 3, 1440),
            ('% [0-9][0-9] Day%', 2, 1440),
            ('% [0-9] Day%', 1, 1440),
            ('% [0-9][0-9] Hour%', 2, 60),
            ('% [0-9] Hour%', 1, 60),
            ('% [0-9][0-9] Minute%', 2, 1),
            ('% [0-9] Minute%', 1, 1)
    ) PAT(Pattern, Digits, Multiplier)
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT PATINDEX(PAT.Pattern, ' ' + D.DurationText) AS Pos
    ) PI
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(D.DurationText, PI.POS, PAT.Digits)) AS Value
    ) V
    WHERE PI.Pos > 0 -- Match found
) C
```

For SQL Server 2022 and later, you can use the STRING_SPLIT() function to produce an ordered list of tokens. From there, you can pair up integer values with the keywords that follow and match them up with a list of known units and multipliers. For each match, the value can be scaled up with the multiplier and fed to the `SUM()` function to yield the result.

```
SELECT *
FROM Duration D
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(PAT.Multiplier * S.Value) AS Minutes
    FROM (
        SELECT
            TRY_CONVERT(INT, S.value) AS Value,
            LEAD(S.value) OVER(ORDER BY S.ordinal) AS Keyword
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(D.DurationText, ' ', 1) S
    ) S
    JOIN (
        VALUES
            ('Day%', 1440),
            ('Hour%', 60),
            ('Minute%', 1)
    ) PAT(Pattern, Multiplier)
        ON S.KeyWord LIKE PAT.Pattern
    WHERE S.Value IS NOT NULL
) C
```

Results (with some extra sample data):

| Id | DurationText | Minutes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 Days 18 Hours 51 Minutes. | 5451 |
| 2 | 3 Days 51 Minutes. | 4371 |
| 3 | 18 Hours. | 1080 |
| 4 | 1 day 1 hour 1 minute. | 1501 |
| 5 | 10000 days 1 hour 1 minute. | 14400061 |
| 6 | Undefined | null |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WGIsBVOd).